# How to give correct path for images in Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

How could I give style background image path in my wordpress child theme index page. I have tried but its not working. I have given my code here.

```
<div class="item" style="background: url('<?php echo 
 get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/about-banner.jpg')">
```

Comment: in view source what path are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use below code.
<div class="item" style="background: url('<?php echo 
 get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/about-banner.jpg')">
```